# Посчитать метки в нарисованном полигоне

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Я наношу на карту метки абонентов в кол-ве около 100 тыс. шт. Посредством файла `json`. Рисую через `myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);`
У каждой метки есть атрибут (Стоимость услуги). Всё отрисовывается, красиво разукрашено, всё чётко. но появилась потребность такого рода: Хочу рисовать на карте произвольную область, и чтобы в каком-то окошке выводилась информация, сколько меток я зацепил этой областью и на какую стоимость. Через что это можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у меня всё получилось. Делал так: рисовал полигон как обычный многоугольник через рисование (есть в примерах Яндекса).

```
var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([], }, {});
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);
myPolygon.editor.startDrawing();
```

добавил событие по щелчку показать кол-во и сумму точек абонентов и их список.

```
myPolygon.events.add('click', function () {})
```

но вывожу всё в примитивный alert().

upd.: сделал через баллун-панель. вроде нормально

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос

Answer (score 0):

[Рисование произвольного полигона](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_custom) есть в примерах Яндекса. [Попадание точек в окружность](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle/) при помощи **searchInside** от **geoQuery** тоже есть в примерах. Вам нужно их объединить и добавить подсчёт содержимого полей стоимости в отобранной группе [**GeoQueryResult**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html).

Comment: Да, спасибо, я этим путем и пошел. Но решил не брать рисовку произвольного полигона, а взять построение полигона как многоугольника с четкими вершинами. Сейчас пытаюсь всё это подружить.

Answer (score 0):

Пример с фильтрацией по нескольким полигонам.

```
MyMap.prototype.filterByPolygons = function (markers) {
    if (!this.polygons.length) {
        return markers;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].found) {
            var found = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < this.polygons.length; j++) {
                var geometry = this.polygons[j].geometry;
                if (geometry.contains(markers[i].geometry.coordinates)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                markers[i].found = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return markers;
};
```