# Как можно ограничить отоброжение точки на карте внутри определенного региона в яндекс картах?

Tags: яндекс-карты

как можно реализовать функционал того что бы точки на карте отоброжались внутри определонного региона (в моем случае страны).

Я использую Object Manager и в нем оказывается есть фильтр, как отфильтровать координаты которые выходят за рамки региона?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1526442/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: Похоже, что вам стоит смотреть на setFilter https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/ObjectManager#setFilter с опорой на этот ответ: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1512877/386299